# Can i add meta keywords with multiple languages?

Tags: web-app, user-research, language, seo

I have a webpage and i want to add meta keywords/description with multiple languages into it. Is it good practice to add it and will it have any improvement regarding seo ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it better suited in Webmasters SE (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Reference this post - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58458/how-can-i-add-use-meta-description-and-meta-keyword-tags-on-a-multi-lingual-webs

From a usability perspective, make sure your meta keywords are in the language the user is expecting. Otherwise, similar to users seeing the wrong language, screen readers will read the wrong language to visually impaired users.

Screen reader example: https://youtu.be/dEbl5jvLKGQ?t=114